# using toJSON() to filter out circular reference from array of objects before writing to .json file

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

I'm using `JSON.stringify()` on array of object before writing to the .json file. I receive an error about circular referencing.

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at TASKS.save (/home/yury.stanev/menlolab/runner/lib/tasks.js:89:27)
    at Timeout.setInterval [as _onTimeout] (/home/yury.stanev/menlolab/runner/lib/tasks.js:124:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

Using `unil.inspect` I've the found the circular reference  line 37 of the following [object](https://pastebin.com/u0h7hz5G). I'm trying to use a custom `toJSON()` method to filter it out. I'm not sure how to actually access the required property to do it. My code is as follows:

```
toJSON() {
    const cleanObj = {};
    for (const prop in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !== '_task' && prop !== '_handle') {
        cleanObj[prop] = this[prop];
      }
    }
    return cleanObj;
  }
```

What's the best way to go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways to solve this issue:

---

One is to use [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) which introduces two functions, `JSON.decycle()` and `JSON.retrocycle()`, which makes it possible to encode and decode cyclical structures and dags into an extended and retrocompatible JSON format.

---

Or you can implement your own solution which will require finding and replacing (or removing) the cyclic references by serializable values.

The snippet below illustrates how to find and filter (thus causing data loss) a cyclic reference by using the `replacer` parameter of `JSON.stringify()`:

```
var circularReference = {otherData: 123};
circularReference.myself = circularReference;

const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

JSON.stringify(circularReference, getCircularReplacer());
```

Please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value) for more information.